# Transform-origin issue

Tags: css

I'm trying to rotate object using: `transform: rotate(90deg);` and applying `transform-origin: right bottom;`. But there I get different transformation behavior depending on where I place `transform-origin`: either to parent element or to `:hover` state.

Why does those differences happens?

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.main:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: right bottom;
}

.main2 {
     transform-origin: right bottom;
}

.main2:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}



/*********BG colors*******/
.main, .main2 {
    background: green;
}

.wrapper {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="main">Transform-origin on :hover state</div>
</div>

    
<div class="wrapper transform">
<div class="main2">Transform-origin on parent element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `.main2`, you're initializing `transform-origin` to `right bottom`, but with `.main`, you're setting the origin on `:hover`.  Because of this, CSS is trying to tween between the default origin (the center of the element) and `right bottom` - creating this odd effect.